# Array $product['item'][ ] = Array - trying to access a specific item in this array

Tags: arrays

This array is setup inside a php foreach loop. I'm trying to access a specific item, but I can't find anything that shows the way this array is defined:

```
$paypal_product['items'][] = array(.....);
```

I want to get the value of  'itm_code'. This is part of the checkout process for a shopping cart so normally there may be multiple items. In this case, the array would only contain a single item since it would make no sense to order multiples (it's a subscription item).

```
foreach($_POST['item_name'] as  $key=>$itmname)
{
    //create items for session
    $paypal_product['items'][] = array(

      'itm_name'=>$_POST["item_name"][$key],
      'itm_price'=>$_POST["amount"][$key],
      'itm_code'=>$_POST['item_code'][$key], 
      'itm_qty'=>$_POST['quantity'][$key],
      'itm_type'=>$_POST['productType'][$key],
      'itm_desc'=>$_POST['description'][$key]
                                        );
}

echo "Product Code: " . $paypal_product['itm_code'][0];
```

I've tried:
    echo "Product Code: " . $paypal_product['itm_code'][0];

as well as some other combinations but clearly I'm not understanding this form of an array.

Answer (score 0):

Lost sight of the bigger picture trying to understand this array. All I need is the $_POST['item_code'] value since this is will be a single item in the cart.